# UIViewController deallocated

Tags: ios7, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

I have a ViewController(root view controller) called Feed. In the viewDidLoad method of feed I am pushing(segue with name X) the loginViewController. After successful login, pop to the feed controller. 
I have another navigation controller where the root view controller have logout button.
After successful logout, again pushing(segue with name Y) the loginViewController. 
Here after viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear called, dealloc also getting called and app crashes.
All these are in a sideMenu view like Facebook, airbnb etc.

App flow is:    **_

               |    NavController_1-->Feed(RootView)-->LoginView(Segue X)
       SideMenu---->NavController_2-->Some Other Controllers
               |_** NavController_3-->Accounts(RootView)-->LoginView(Segue Y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I came to know the reason for crash after killing 2days of time.
The main issue is with my side menu .i.e PHAirViewController. This internally having a UIViewController category. When I tap on login, app switch to facebook login page and dealloc method of this category is getting called. I just tried by commenting the dealloc and login/logout works without a crash. Don't know what the hell with this dealloc.